# C - Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I have read about 5 different questions on the same error, but I still can't find what's the problem with my code.

main.c

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    //graph_t * g = graph_create(128); //I commented this line out to make sure graph_create was not causing this.
    graph_t * g;
    g->cap; //This line gives that error.
    return 1;
}
```

.c

```
struct graph {
    int cap;
    int size;
};
```

.h

```
typedef struct graph graph_t;
```

Thanks!

Comment: @GregBrown: He is getting dereferencing pointer to incomplete type error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that since the struct is defined in a different source file. The whole point of the typedef is to hide the data from you. There are probably functions such as `graph_cap` and `graph_size` that you can call that will return the data for you.

If this is your code, you should define `struct graph` inside the header file so all files that that include this header will be able to have the definition of it.

Comment: Thanks, this makes perfect sense. Also thanks to other people who also responded to my questions.

Answer (score 1):

When the compiler is compiling `main.c` it needs to be able to *see* the definition of `struct graph` so that it knows there exists a member named `cap`. You need to move the definition of the structure from the *.c* file to the *.h* file.

An alternate method, if you need `graph_t` to be an [opaque data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type), is to create accessor functions that take a `graph_t` pointer and return the field value. For example,

graph.h

```
int get_cap( graph_t *g );
```

graph.c

```
int get_cap( graph_t *g ) { return g->cap; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Must be the order you have things defined.  The typedef line needs to show up in the header file that is included by the file that has main().

Otherwise it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

`lala.c`

```
#include "lala.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    //graph_t * g = graph_create(128); //I commented this line out to make sure graph_create was not causing this.
    graph_t * g;
    g->cap; //This line gives that error.
    return 1;
}
```

`lala.h`

```
#ifndef LALA_H
#define LALA_H

struct graph {
    int cap;
    int size;
};

typedef struct graph graph_t;

#endif
```

This compiles without problems with:

```
gcc -Wall lala.c -o lala
```