# Dereferencing pointer to an incomplete type

Tags: c, pointers

I am writing a simple program to add two complex number using struct. All goes well except that when printing the values, I get an error that I am dereferencing an incomplete pointer.

Here is the code:

```
struct complexNumber * n1 = (struct complexNumber *) createNumber(10,10);
struct complexNumber * n2 = (struct complexNumber *) createNumber(03,12);
struct complexNumber * n3 = (struct complexNumber *) addComplexNunbers(n1,n2);

printf("Real Part: %d Imaginary Part: %d",n3->real,n3->imaginary);
```

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/q/2700646/489590   http://stackoverflow.com/q/9606435/489590

Comment: Have a look down on the right side of this page, and see how many related question referring your question's title already exists. You most propaply have been pointed to those when creating this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `include` the header fine, which defines `struct complexNumber`.

Comment: It is in a different `.c` file I created. How do I add that ?

Comment: @LittleChild Is this C or C++?

Comment: @LittleChild - you need to move the full definition of `struct complexNumber` into a header file (`.h`) and include it where it's necessary.

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of using incomplete type is to make the program able to use a pointer to an object, without knowing the implementation of said object.

Therefore, it never makes any sense to access the pointed-to contents of an incomplete type.